# Orchard CMS Admin Error

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

In the admin section of my Orchard CMS v1.8 site, I am getting two errors and I don't know if they are related or separate.

When I try to go to the Modules page I get the following error.

> [DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found with 'Orchard.Environment.AutofacUtil.DynamicProxy2.ConstructorFinderWrapper' on type 'Orchard.Modules.Controllers.AdminController' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
>   Cannot resolve parameter 'Orchard.Recipes.Services.IRecipeHarvester recipeHarvester' of constructor 'Void .ctor(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Orchard.Modules.Events.IExtensionDisplayEventHandler], Orchard.IOrchardServices, Orchard.Modules.Services.IModuleService, Orchard.Data.Migration.IDataMigrationManager, Orchard.Reports.Services.IReportsCoordinator, Orchard.Environment.Extensions.IExtensionManager, Orchard.Environment.Features.IFeatureManager, Orchard.Recipes.Services.IRecipeHarvester, Orchard.Recipes.Services.IRecipeManager, Orchard.Environment.Descriptor.Models.ShellDescriptor, Orchard.Environment.Configuration.ShellSettings, Orchard.DisplayManagement.IShapeFactory)'.]
>      Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Activators\Reflection\ReflectionActivator.cs:118
>      Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Resolving\InstanceLookup.cs:79
>      Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Resolving\InstanceLookup.cs:61
>      Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Resolving\ResolveOperation.cs:123
>      Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Resolving\ResolveOperation.cs:85
>      Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Lifetime\LifetimeScope.cs:232
>      Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\ResolutionExtensions.cs:736
>      Orchard.Mvc.OrchardControllerFactory.TryResolve(WorkContext workContext, Object serviceKey, T& instance) in c:\Orchard\src\Orchard\Mvc\OrchardControllerFactory.cs:26
>      Orchard.Mvc.OrchardControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) in c:\Orchard\src\Orchard\Mvc\OrchardControllerFactory.cs:70
>      System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +103
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +267
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +95
>      Orchard.Mvc.Routes.HttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) in c:\Orchard\src\Orchard\Mvc\Routes\ShellRoute.cs:152
>      System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +921
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +137

At the top of every page in the admin, I have the following error displayed.

> The assembly reference 'Orchard.Recipes' could not be loaded for module 'Orchard.Setup'.
>
> There are generally a few ways to solve this issue: 
>    1. Install any dependent module. 
>    2. Remove the assembly reference from the project file if it's not needed. 
>    3. Ensure the assembly reference is present in the 'bin' directory of the module. 
>    4. Ensure the assembly reference is present in the 'bin' directory of the application. 
>    5. Specify the strong name of the assembly (name, version, culture, publickey) if the assembly is present in the GAC.

Can anyone tell me what I am missing with this installation?

Thanks!

Comment: Dear, Orchard has dynamic module loader to load active modules and it's dependencies, but if any module failed to build orchard will exclude it, and there is 'Orchard.Recipes' core module, and it seems not loaded correctly in your case, can you check 'Dependencies' folder under 'App_Data' to see if it contains "Orchard.Recipes.dll", if not you can try to delete all files from this folder and restart your server to let orchard rebuild these dependencies.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but still have the error displayed at the top of the admin page and I am not able to get to the module page.  I did verify that the dependencies folder was rebuilt but it still does not contain the "Orchard.Recipes.dll".  Any other suggestions?